# Extra permissions on Google Play

Tags: android

I added only 3 permissions on my android app manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, users get many more permissions than above like:

```
1.Contacts
find accounts on the device
2.Location
approximate location (network-based)
3.Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
4.Storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
5.Other
full network access
view network connections
use accounts on the device
```

I don't know why so many permissions are asked from users who installed my app, is it because of admob ads I added?

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
..
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
..
}
```

Comment: what is your gradle dependencies? The library you used?

Comment: @HugoGresse I updated the question with dependencies and I had used apache poi libraries.

Comment: Also read this https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html